# Need help with proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come up with an answer, but im not sure if its right if someone would please take a look i would really appreciate it.

Suppose V is a real vector space, $T\in L(V, V )$, and V has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of T. If A is the matrix corresponding to T, show that $tr(A^2)\geqslant0$.

My proof:

$tr(A)$=sum of eigenvalues of A. 
$tr(A^2)$=sum of eigenvalues of $A^2$=sum of squares of eigenvalues of $A$ ie>0.
As eigenvalues of $A^2$=squares of eigenvalues of A>0.
$Tx=\lambda x$
$T\cdot Tx=T\cdot\lambda x=\lambda\cdot\lambda x=\lambda^2x$. 
Thus, $tr(A^2)\geqslant0$.

Comment: Let $\sigma(A)$ be the spectrum of $A$, the set of distinct eigenvalues of $A$. Your argument shows that $$\lambda \in \sigma(A) \implies \lambda^2 \in \sigma(A^2)$$ You haven't shown the other direction however. Is it possible for $A^2$ to have _other_ eigenvalues which are not squares of the eigenvalues of $A$? You can show that this is not possible by using the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable, which you have not used at all yet. The result actually _is_ true for general matrices, but your argument is not sufficient here.

Comment: Well, say for example that our $A$ is some large $n\times n$ matrix with just a single eigenvalue $\lambda$ repeated $n$ times. Then $A^2$ also has $n$ eigenvalues (up to multiplicity). Certainly $\lambda^2$ is _one of the_ eigenvalues for $A^2$, but have you shown that it is the _only_ eigenvalue? Why can't there be others (which are possibly negative)?

Comment: Well, what does the matrix of $T$ look like with respect to a basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: You claim that _"since A is diagonalizable then it is not possible for A^2 to have other eigenvalues which are not squares of the eigenvalues of A"_ but you have not shown this anywhere. $A$ is not only diagonalizable, but as the matrix of $T$ corresponding to an eigenbasis, $A$ itself _is_ diagonal. Now since $A$ is diagonal, what can you say about the eigenvalues of $A$? What about $A^2$ then?

Comment: What do you mean by "eigenvalues of A must be in the basis"? Eigenvalues are scalars, not vectors.

Comment: Exactly. There you have it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Here's a more cleaned-up version. The matrix of $T$ with respect to a basis of eigenvectors is a diagonal matrix so $A$ is diagonal. It follows that $A^2$ is also diagonal with diagonal entries which are the squares of $A$'s entries. Therefore the trace of $A^2$, being a sum of the diagonal entries, is a sum of squares and so is necessarily non-negative. Notice here that we didn't even need to invoke anything about eigenvalues (except to claim that $A$ is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: Please improve your title